# present perfect can be replaced with past

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I was watching a film in which appears a conversation like this.
two persons were talking in front of the king then after the conversation finished the king says: "must go to bed, I'm tired but I'm glad we've have had this conversation" why he says we have had this conversation. shouldn't he say we had this conversation?
which usage of present perfect is this?

Comment: It's the ***normal*** use - the king's choice of verb form reflects the fact that the (past) having of the conversation is particularly *relevant to time of speaking* (because he's glad about it ***now***, regardless of whether or not he felt like that *during* the conversation).

Answer (score 1):

The conversation has just ended, a very short while ago and the king is affected by its results = he is glad about it now. If he had said: "I'm glad we had that conversation yesterday, this morning, an hour ago", etc. past simple would be appropriate.